# How to Add Method to React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I have a component with code as such:

```
const Abc: React.FC<AbcTypes> = ({...}) => {...}

Abc.getLayout = () => {...}
```

I am unclear how to define/ extend the method `getLayout` on Abc component in Typescript?

Comment: Bad idea. Please use `useState` or `useEffect` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are asking how to type this, then you could do this:

```
const Abc: React.FC<AbcTypes> & { getLayout: () => SomeType } = ({...}) => {...}

Abc.getLayout = () => {...}
```

If you are asking for a way to define imperative API for your components then [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) is what you are looking for.

This will allow the parent component to attach a ref to `Abc` and call the methods you define.

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
type AbcRef = {
  getLayout: () => string[]
}
const Abc = forwardRef<AbcRef>((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getLayout: () => ['abc'],
  }))

  return <div>Abc</div>
})

const Parent: FC = () => {
  const abcRef = useRef<AbcRef>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(abcRef.current?.getLayout())
  }, [])

  return <Abc ref={abcRef} />
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it.

Comment: Hey @thedude, quick question. Is attaching a function to a react functional component better or using useImperativeHandle? For us, just attaching a function is doing the trick, but people are asking us to not do it. So useImperativeHook seems like our only option. Wondering what are the pros and cons of both.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh not sure I understand, perhaps create a new question here with more details

Comment: @thedude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73694563/attach-a-method-function-to-a-functional-component-in-react

Comment: Used to look so much cleaner with classes.. I guess it's just the way the progress goes.. Getting rid of OOP and ending up with huge load of nonsense boilerplate code everywhere..