# Attach a method/function to a functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In a class component we can do this:

```
class Block extends React.Component {
  public static customFunction1(){
    return whatever;
  }
  
  public static customFunction2(){
    return whatever;
  }

  render(){
     return <Component />
  }
}
```

So with the above component, we can directly use `<Block />` wherever we want, and also utilize `Block.customFunction()` and the other one as well.

Now talking about Functional Component:

We tried doing

```
const Block = () => {
  return <Component />
}

Block.customFunction1 = () => {
  return whatever;
}

Block.customFunction2 = () => {
  return whatever;
}
```

People are not recommending the above approach. I'm wondering what should be the approach which attaching methods to Functional Component?

Comment: Why not passing them as props - `Block({ canClick, canSpan }) {}`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with those functions?

Comment: Those functions are being used by parent component.

Comment: It's not really clear what the goal is here.  Where/how/why are these functions being used?  Do you have a [mcve] which demonstrates the purpose of this approach?

Comment: It's unlikely that this will work the way you want. Block.canClick will be the same for every instance of Block in your entire app and will have limited access to state information. Can you describe your use case? There's probably a better pattern for it.

Comment: The parent component should control whether the child is clickable/span-able.

Comment: My answer: Don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is actually a real relevance to do it like that. If you would use TypeScript for instance, you would make typing of this part of the code harder and there are actually other "reserved" properties that are used by React, e.g. "propTypes" or "displayName". That is the reason why you shouldn't do it, as you did it.

Another approach just for grouping these kind of elements that is more clean is the following:

```js
Block.Component = () => {}

Block.onClick = (props) => {
  return true/false
} 

Block.onSpan = () => {
  return true/false
}
```

Now you are not attaching the properties to the component that is used by React internally, but still have the grouping and flexibility you need.

Comment: Ahh that's interesting.
So Block.Component, can be used in any other element simply as `<Block />`? or we need to use `<Block.Component />`?

Comment: It would be the latter: `<Block.Component />`

Comment: I see so much limitations with functional components its unbelievable..